# How much will I get from an early withdrawal from a 401k and Roth 401k with employee contributions after taxes and penalties?

Tags: united-states, 401k, roth-401k, employer-match, home-equity

I am planning to buy a house and want to maximize my cash available.
In my 401k account, I have a distribution like this:
(x+x1 gains)+(y+y1 gains)+(z+z1 gains)
where
x: 401k,
y: roth 401k,
z: employer contribution.

I am <59 years and married. My tax range is about 30%. Can you please let me know how much I will get in-hand if I withdraw now?
Thanks

Comment: Are you differentiating between the original contributions in these accounts and the gains on those contributions because you know that the contributions and the gains are treated differently during withdrawal?  Or is there some other reason for that?

Comment: You are explicitly allowed to borrow from your 401k for the purpose of a home downpayment. There's a few gotchas, but I'm reasonably sure it's a better option than what you're planning.

Comment: I think on the roth, original contributions and gains are taxed differently during withdrawal. That's why I made that distinction. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Will the 401(k) provider permit a withdrawal? They are not required to.

But if they do allow the withdraw a 10% penalty would apply. Instead of paying 40% in tax to net 60, why not borrow 50% and not destroy your account?